# C: loop on scanf

Tags: c, scanf

```
    char buf[1024] = {0};

    // send a message
    if(status == 0) {
        while(1) {
            printf("Enter message : ");
            scanf("%1023[^\n]", buf);
            fflush(stdin);
            if(strcmp(buf,"quit")==0)
                break;
            status = write(s, buf, strlen(buf));
            fflush(stdout);
            memset(buf,0,sizeof buf);
        }
    }
```

For my scanf, I want to take in spaces. However if I run this part of the code, the "Enter message: " will be in an infinite loop.

If I change scanf to "%s" only then it works normally but i cannot take in inputs with space in between.

Could anyone help in spotting how come it is throwing infinite loop or any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Don't use `fflush(stdin)`, it's undefined behavior

Comment: Why are you using `write` and `fwrite`?

Comment: I would guess that the newline stays in the buffer, so subsequent calls to `scanf` read zero characters.

Comment: @immibis what else would it be?

Comment: @user3121023 The perfect solution is `fgets()`

Comment: Step 1) When having trouble with user input, check the return values from inputs functions.

Comment: @user3121023 in that case, blank lines would not end the input  (may or may not be suitable for OP)

Comment: @iharob is it? the school taught us to use fflush(stdin) after scanf. Confused about it when you say it is undefinited behaviour.

Comment: @EdHeal using write to write message to bluetooth device using rfcomm and socket.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` works with some platforms/compilers to flush `stdin`.  Yet the C standard does not specify that, instead it is undefined behavior.  It is not portable.

Comment: @chux I see. Thanks for that valuable info! Definitely expands my knowledge on C!

Comment: Concerning "school taught us to use fflush(stdin) after scanf.", It would be interesting to learn your professor's view on the lack of portability of `fflush(stdin)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf()` simply has too many ways to go wrong reading a *line*.  Use `fgets()`

```
char buf[1024] = {0};

// send a message
if(status == 0) {
    while(1) {
        printf("Enter message : ");
        if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) break;
        //scanf("%1023[^\n]", buf);
        //fflush(stdin);

        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0'; // lop off potential \n

        if(strcmp(buf,"quit")==0)
            break;


        status = write(s, buf, strlen(buf));
        // fflush(stdout);
        memset(buf,0,sizeof buf);
    }
}
```