# What is the reason for scanf() inside the while loop not working?

Tags: c

`Scanf()` inside while is not working. Without while it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
        int test,i,l=0,j;
        char name[100],name1[100];
        scanf("%d",&test);
        while(test--)
        {
                scanf("%[^\n]s",name);
                l=strlen(name);
                for(i=0;i<=l;i++)
                {
                        if (name[i]>=97 && name[i]<=122)
                        {
                                name1[i]= name[i]-32;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                name1[i]= name[i];
                        }
                } 
                printf("%s",name1);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I don't get the error.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? You need to describe exactly what's happening, what you want to happen, and what you've tried.

Comment: Use `toupper()` to convert letters to uppercase, not your own code.

Comment: Thanks @Carcigenicate

Comment: Thanks @Carcigenicate 
if i put several blank spaces at the start of a string the blank spaces are omitted while printing.

Comment: Suggest using `fgets()`   [C: loop on scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281009/c-loop-on-scanf)

Comment: @Trojan you passed name without & in scanf function scanf("%[^\n]s",name); that is not true make it correct like scanf("%[^\n]s",&name); and try it